# I am trying to take an 1D slice from 2D numpy array, but something goes wrong

Tags: numpy, python-3.7, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am trying to filter evident measurement mistakes from my data using the 3-sigma rule. x is a numpy array of measurement points and y is an arrray of measured values. To remove wrong points from my data, I zip x.tolist() and y.tolist(), then filter by the second element of each tuple, then I need to convert my zip back into two lists. I tried to first covert my list of tuples into a list of lists, then convert it to numpy 2D array and then take two 1D-slices of it. It looks like the first slice is correct, but then it outputs the following:

```
x = np.array(list(map(list, list(filter(flt, list(zap))))))[:, 0]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
x = np.array(readCol(0, l))
y = np.array(readCol(1, l))
n = len(y)

stdev = np.std(y)
mean = np.mean(y)

print("Stdev is: " + str(stdev))
print("Mean is: " + str(mean))

def flt(n):
    global mean
    global stdev
    global x
    if abs(n[1] - mean) < 3*stdev:
        return True
    else:
        print('flt function finds an error: ' + str(n[1]))
        return False


def filtration(N):
    print(Fore.RED + 'Filtration function launched')
    global y
    global x
    global stdev
    global mean
    zap = zip(x.tolist(), y.tolist())
    for i in range(N):
        print(Fore.RED + ' Filtration step number ' + str(i) + Style.RESET_ALL)
        y = np.array(list(map(list, list(filter(flt, list(zap))))))[:, 1]
        print(Back.GREEN + 'This is y: \n' + Style.RESET_ALL)
        print(y)
        x = np.array(list(map(list, list(filter(flt, list(zap))))))[:, 0]
        print(Back.GREEN + 'This is x: \n' + Style.RESET_ALL)
        print(x)
        print('filtration fuction main step')
        stdev = np.std(y)
        print('second step')
        mean = np.mean(y)
        print('third step')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to test the problem line step by step?

```
x = np.array(list(map(list, list(filter(flt, list(zap))))))[:, 0]
```

for example:

```
temp = np.array(list(map(list, list(filter(flt, list(zap))))))
print(temp.shape, temp.dtype)
x = temp[:, 0]
```

Further break down might be needed, but since `[:,0]` is the only indexing operation in this line, I'd start there.

Without further study of the code and/or some examples, I'm not going to try to speculate what the nested `lists` are doing.

The error sounds like `temp` is not 2d, contrary to your expectations.  That could be because `temp` is object dtype, and composed of lists the vary in length.  That seems to be common problem when people make arrays from downloaded databases.

Comment: Thank you! I still have no idea what is wrong with the code above, but after creation of a temp array from which I take slices it works fine.

`temp = np.array(list(map(list, list(filter(flt, list(zap))))))
 x = temp[:, 0]
 y = temp[:, 1]`

Comment: P.S. : temp IS 2D